# .htaccess rewrite blank spaces with - ("%20" to "-")

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove %20 on my link to - (dash),

My .htaccess is like that right now,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ icerik.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

For example,

site.com/vision-and-mision, 
site.com/do-re-mi-fa-so-la-si.

Actually I searched something but the informations were very specific and I'm confused

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Replace whitespace with hyphens, set the environment variable,
# and restart the rewriting process. This essentially loops
# until all whitespace has been converted.

RewriteRule ^([^\s]*)\s(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=whitespace:yes,N]

# Then, once that is done, check if the whitespace variable has
# been set and, if so, redirect to the new URI. This process ensures
# that the URI is rewritten in a loop *internally* so as to avoid
# multiple browser redirects.

RewriteCond %{ENV:whitespace} yes
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Then add your rules afterwards:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /icerik.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If this is working for you, and you would like to make the redirects cached by browsers and search engines, change `302` to `301`.