# .htaccess remove whitespace

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem that can not handle a few days. When I try to share link in Facebook, photos from the link I shared just not show and discovered that this problem is that the names of the images and/or folder has a whitespace. 
My link is okay but the link of the images is not good.
How I can with `.htaccess` to `rewrite` only folder and/or images name and replace whitespace with underscore(lowdash)?

For example(image link in the link):

```
www.example.com/image/cache/catalog/new laptops/Asus x/Asus x-710x410.jpg  // Bad
www.example.com/image/cache/catalog/new_laptops/Asus_x/Asus_x-710x410.jpg  // Good
```

I would be very grateful if you share some idea how I can do this because for several days I can not cope with the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be a bad idea: What if the original filename already has underscore? Have you tried to replace spaces with '%20' sending link to facebook?

Comment: See @mikeRockett 's Answer here =>


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368651/htaccess-rewrite-blank-spaces-with-20-to/35369189#35369189

Comment: @Starkeen I dont think that is the answer of my problem.

Comment: Does `http://www.example.com/image/cache/catalog/new_laptops/Asus_x/Asus_x-710x410.jpg` work fine in your browser and load the correct image?